# few styling problems

Tags: css

[http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/6803/32007451.jpg http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/6803/32007451.jpg](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/6803/32007451.jpg)

I have two problems with my friendlisting box.
1. Images are set 100px in width but they vary in height. Problem here is, friendlisting div is not extending along with image's height as it should. As a result image overpositioned on bottom border.
2. Commonfriends div needs to extend in height and fully fill friendlisting box. Not happening.

I spent hours to fix these two issues, just couldn't make it. Any advise appreciated!

My html

```
<div class="friendlisting">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/3375/8623375.jpg" alt="xxxx" class="profile" /></a>
                                <div class="userinfo">
                                    <span><strong><a href="#">George Lexington</a></strong></span>
                                    <span>Bruges, Belgium</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="commonfriends">13 common friends</div>
                                <div class="tools">
                                    <span><img src="images/icons/user_add.png" />Add to friend list</span>
                                    <span><img src="images/icons/email_edit.png" />Send Message</span>     
                                </div>                        
                            </div>
```

css

```
#content .friendlisting { min-height:40px; padding:5px 0 5px; border-bottom:1px solid #DDD; }
#content .friendlisting img.profile { float:left; width:100px;  }
#content .friendlisting .userinfo { float:left; width: 200px; padding:10px; }
#content .friendlisting .userinfo span { display:block; }
#content .friendlisting .commonfriends { float:left; width:150px; height:100%; background:#ffe996; } 
#content .friendlisting .commonfriends:hover { background:#FEDF62; } 
#content .friendlisting .tools { float:left; width:160px; }
#content .friendlisting .tools span { display:block; }
```

Comment: You might have more luck posting this question in http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 1):

you could try using a clearing div like this:

```
<div class="friendlisting">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.hurriyet.com.tr/_np/3375/8623375.jpg" alt="xxxx" class="profile" /></a>
    <div class="userinfo">

        <span><strong><a href="#">George Lexington</a></strong></span>
        <span>Bruges, Belgium</span>
    </div>
    <div class="commonfriends">13 common friends</div>
    <div class="tools">
        <span><img src="images/icons/user_add.png" />Add to friend list</span>
        <span><img src="images/icons/email_edit.png" />Send Message</span>     
    </div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div> 
</div>
```

or if you dont like the in-line style

```
.clear
{
  clear:both;
}
```

then `<div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: also i think you can use the clear on the commonfriends div too and remove the height property

Comment: I have clearing div between my friendlisting divs already. But I am not sure what of my problems would this solve?